# how to see the home or recent files in guest account of admin account

Tags: virtualbox, permissions, printing, login, password

I want to see my important videos and images from a guest account which is in my brother's administrator account and the main account is locked by my brother.i have only a guest account and i want to see my document which is kept in home or recent file in the main account
i can't break the password  b'cause i have on permission to do this .
Tell me the way of enter in the home or recent folder/file of administrator account without breaking the password
how can i directly enter in the main account from a guest account?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the File Located

```
/home/youruser/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

This file will be in metadata format And i Don't know How to View it ...

Comment: /home/youruser/.local/share/recently-used.xbel, how can i use this,plz tell me in details,